# Refinancing Home Loan

Tags: loans, home-loan, refinance

You have been living in the house you bought 7 years ago for $300,000. At that time, you took out a loan for 80% of the house at a fixed rate 15-year loan at an annual stated rate of 8.0%. You have just paid off the 84th monthly payment. Interest rates have meanwhile dropped steadily to 6.0% per year, and you think it is finally time to refinance the remaining balance over the residual loan life. But there is a catch. The fee to refinance your loan is $5,000. Should you refinance the remaining balance? How much would you save/lose if you decided to refinance?

Yes, gain $7,287.20

No, lose $12,287.20

Yes, gain $12,287.20

No, lose $7,287.20

What I tried:

I tried calculating like this:

I calculated the interest we are paying currently and balance after 7 years and they are as follows but when I calculate the interest after refinance and calculate profit loss the answers don't match?

240000 * (0.08/12) * (1 + 1/((1 + (0.08/12))^180 - 1) ) =2293.565 --> Current Interest

(2293.565 + (1 + (0.08/12))^(84) * ((0.08/12) * 240000 - 2293.565))/(0.08/12) --> Balance after 7 years == 162242

Comment: This looks like a homework question. In order to make any answers more applicable to a wider audience it helps to add more details. What exactly do you need help understanding? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Nosjack, I update what I did. It's not a homework question by the way and it would be great if you could help.

Comment: @SarahKaiser Those interest rates are not current market rates which suggests it is a homework problem.

Comment: That's not necessarily an exact duplicate, but might provide a useful answer.

Comment: @yoozer8, thanks but it doesn't answer my question

Comment: @PeteB., it's a practice problem of an online course.

Comment: If you keep the old mortgage, you'll pay $M1(t) in interest during month t. If you refinance, you'll pay $M2(t). You are looking for the number of months B where sum(M1(i), i=1..B) - sum(M2(i), i=1..B) exceeds $5000. If you sell the house (thus paying off the mortgage) in less than B months, you would have been better off saving the $5000. After B months, you will have saved more in interest than the re-fi cost.

Comment: If you refinance, you can also take into account not just how much less interest you'll pay based the lower rate, but how much you save by having a lower minimum monthly payment (because you've extended your payment window by 8 years).

Comment: @SarahKaiser Sorry it wasn't sufficiently helpful. I am pretty sure we do have a question and answer somewhere that explains really well exactly how to figure this out (how much you save - or lose - in the long run, when you break even, etc.), but I haven't been able to find it

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe these proposed answers are correct; I match your numbers, and verified with a couple of online calculators.  I get a savings of around $10k (after factoring in the $5k cost, varies slightly depending on if you finance this amount or not, but never getting to their numbers).

Comment: How do you define the amount saved?

Comment: [sum of payments in current mortgage] - [sum of payments in refinanced mortgage including the refi fee], no?

Comment: Adding amounts of money at different times is not usually helpful in comparing interest earning/paying scenarios. An alternative:  Assuming that the mortgage holder switches to the 6% lender after payment 84, and keeps making the same 2293.55 payments to this lender for 96 months, he can borrow enough to pay off the balance, pay off the penalty, and have 7287.20 extra.  Same payments, same mortgage discharged, extra money in hand So the course creators obviously had the cash situation as of payment 84 as the criteria for amount saved/lost...

Comment: @DJohnM Why would you assume the payments stay the same?  That's not how any mortgage works that I'm familiar with.  I suppose you're correct as to what they're assuming, but it's something that absolutely would need to be stated in the question.  The normal way you'd do this is to assume the $5k is paid from the refinance funds, meaning if you're not intending to get any net cash out you'd add the $5k to the refinance amount (so refinance 167k instead of 162k), but that's again an assumption (just a more normal one).

Comment: That said, I think what you say is worth an answer, if the question were open - unfortunately it's not; I'd be comfortable with you editing it into mine if you like (and we could CW the answer, also).